# Event fires only on the first click angular - 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I trying to create file upload inside my angular app but I have s strange issue that the event fires only for the first click.

*template*

```
 <input 
        multiple
        type="file" 
        (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
        id="file"
        class="upload-box__btn__file-input"/>
      <label class="upload-box__btn__file-label" for="file">Upload file from pc</label>
```

*component*

```
onFileSelected(event: Event) {
    console.log(event)
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    // if (file.length >= 1) {
    //   this.fileToUpload = file;
    // }
  }
```

Comment: even when selecting different file ?

Comment: @Pranav C Balan  No. Thanks

Comment: it works for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ued1aj

Comment: Do you want a `click` or a `change` event? those are two different events.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have put a change event on the `input type file` and it will only be fired if the selected file is different.